# retrieve the Package.Module.Class name from a (Python) class/type

Tags: python

Right, say I've got this structure: (Which I happen to actually have)

- Interface (folder/Package)

  - Test.py (module)

    - Test (class)

Now I want to get this whole structure (Interface.Test.Test) as a string stored somewhere.
I know I can use `type(myTestObjectInstance)` or `myTestObjectInstance.__class__` But that retrieves me a type object, which prints like `<class 'Interface.Test.Test'>`

But from there on I don't know how to get the actual structure part. I can of course just parse the string, but I suppose there is a more easy way of doing that?

[edit]
Larsmans has provided an answer but it doesn't fully answer what I would like to do:
His answer will not work if all I've got provided is that type object itself (`type(myTestObjectInstance)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`inspect.getmodule`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule) you can (sometimes) find the module in which an object was defined, e.g.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmodule(defaultdict)
<module 'collections' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/collections.pyc'>
```

The module name can be found using `__name__`. Note that the defining module need not be the one you imported from due to re-exports:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> inspect.getmodule(csr_matrix).__name__
'scipy.sparse.csr'
```

Comment: That indeed works, done it this way:  
`name = "{0}.{1}".format(inspect.getmodule(item.GetObj()).__name__,item.GetObj().__class__.__name__)`  
That leaves me with "Interface.Test.Test"
I'll leave the question open for an hour or two, to see if any other answers come in, before I accept yours.

Comment: I just found out that am not fully satisfied yet with this implementation. What if, I've only got the type object of class Test? How would that work out? (Will update question)

Comment: Skip that, got it working: `def test(t):
    return "{0}.{1}".format(inspect.getmodule(Test).__name__, t.__name__)`